# Account Linking Failed

Tags: facebook, bots, botframework

When user hits account linking button, it opens a new window. 
Is that ok ?

Than, in that window i'm rendering html page with account/password fields. 
When user provide that credentials, i'm checking in database and return user e-mail if user exists.

That's ok.

I'm creating redirect url this way :

```
var redirect_uri = getUrlParameter('redirect_uri');
        console.log(redirect_uri);
        var account_linking_token = getUrlParameter('account_linking_token');
        console.log(account_linking_token);
```

My getUrlParameter function :

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
        var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
            sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
            sParameterName,
            i;

        for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
            sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

            if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
                return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
            }
        }
    };
```

Then :

My redirect url :

```
 var r2 = redirect_uri + "=" + account_linking_token + "&authorization_code=" + response.message;
```

message.response is an e-mail.

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/account-linking/authentication) is mentioned that authorization_code can be specified by developer. For example, username, email, etc.

At the end, account linking fails [image].

Any help?

Comment: Bump, @ejadib  :)

Comment: So what is the actual value of your redirect URI, of the `r2` variable?

Comment: I fixed this. Everything works properly. I didn't clear cache and cookies :)

Comment: So @BobSwager clearing cache and cookies fixed the issue for you? I'm still seeing it for me.

Comment: I fixed this issue. If you have troubles to add, you can open a new thread.

Comment: @BobSwager how did you fix it?

Comment: What is your issue ? Where do you have problems ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are subscribing to the messaging_account_linking event.